# react native : calling multiple functions onPress

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to call multiple `functions(not arrow function)` using button `onPress`?

I know that I could call multiple arrow functions like this :

```
onPress={() => { this.functionOne(); this.functionTwo();}}
```

But what if I want to call multiple functions without an `arrow function`? I tried this but this won't work.

```
onPress={this.functionOne, this.functionTwo}
```

Answer (score 5):

Best way of doing this is have a one function which call your all functions,

```
func = () => {
   this.functionOne(); 
   this.functionTwo();
}

onPress={this.func}
```

or you can pass array of functions and call them in child component,

Parent:

```
onPress=[this.functionOne, this.functionTwo]
```

Child:

```
this.props.onPress.map(func=>{
   func()
})
```